# Testing a flaky API in React - what is the right approach?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, postman

I work on a React project (using CRA and TypeScript) that relies on an API that is rather flaky. It gets changed a lot by some other developer so things break frequently. I am really struggling to keep the frontend stable.

I have created TypeScript types that describe the JSON I expect from an API call.

Here is an example of such a type:

```
export type EnvDataResponse = {
    id: number;
    value: string;
}
```

Here is an example of fetching the corresponding data using Axios:

import axios from 'axios';

```
const api = {
  getEnvData: ():Promise<EnvDataResponse[]> => axios.get('/envData')
}

export default api;
```

I wonder now how I can test that API to ensure `axios.get('/envData')` returns a JSON that follows the data schema of `type EnvDataResponse`. I need some mechanism that warns me when the API all of a sudden sends back different data because the backend guy has changed the API without informing me.

Jest does not seem to be the right candidate as it only tests components and relies on a mock API, correct? I need to test the API itself, not components. Would implementing tests in Postman be the right approach?

Comment: Yes, testing in Postman would be a good approach. If you're wanting to keep all of your tests together, you could create End to End tests with a tool like Cypress or Playwright.

Comment: If you just want to check the API meets your expectations, that's really nothing to do with React. You can test it with anything that can make requests, in any test runner (it seems like you have Jest and Axios, which would work just fine) then run that on a schedule so you find out promptly if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with TS is that believes that the data creation is correct. The  if you dont validate it, you will do all the hard work to type everything and it will crash due type error.

I believe that 2 main practices should be implemented.

For frontend:

It should validate the backend and give a warning if in staging/debug or Just log in production in case of error. Ypu can use libs such as ajv (my favorite) to do the task easily.
https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html

For backend:

All the APIs should be unit tested accordingly to the frontend. Any breaking change needs to be comunicated and the frontend will check the use and correct it.